# USB tethering via moto phone

Tags: usb, laptop, android, tethering

My motto phone will tether to my windows laptop okay via usb tethering. But when I connect the phone to my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop the option to tether via usb is not highlighted, and therefore not a option.The usb leads are okay because the phone is showing as charging from the laptop. I have set the phone up as a mobile hotspot and I’m currently using that method to tether. But I would prefer to tether direct from the usb. Can anyone advise please?

Comment: Please edit and add the exact brand/model and OS version. Also some cables are for charging only.

Comment: The phone is Moto E 2nd Generation with 4G LTE Android 6.0. When I get to the USB tethering option it tells me that the USB is not connected. But the battery indicator on the phone is showing that it is charging? The toggle does not respond.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Moto G 2nd Gen, on Android 6.0.

In the phone : Apps > Settings > More (from wireless & networks section) >Tethering & mobile hotspot > USB tethering.(there is an on/off toggle)

Once activated the phone will show "USB tethering active" in the pull down.

On Ubuntu, (I am using lubuntu 16.04) click the network icon. You should see a wired connection option (or an additional wired connection option number 2) appear.Click on its name - and you will be connected.

Comment: The phone is Moto E 2nd Generation with 4G LTE Android 6.0. When I get to the USB tethering option it tells me that the USB is not connected. But the battery indicator on the phone is showing that it is charging? The toggle does not respond.

Comment: I would try a different cable and also ensure the cable is going directly into the PC and not via any hub/extension or adapters.Also even today,not all usb ports are equal.Try plugging into a usb 2.0 socket rather than usb 3.0 (blue inside). On my one of my PCs, the usb 3.0 sockets sometime reject certain hardware (this should not be the case - but sadly it is).

Comment: Nothing to add to the above. I already mentioned the cable in the first comment above. The USB ports are also relevant as explained by @linuxbun .Whatever  that is, it's not Ubuntu related. It's your phone recognizing the USB connection as a charger, not a data connection, hence the unavailable options.

Comment: I think you are right about the usb  cable the original has gone missing.

Comment: I will get a moto one and let you both know.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a new usb cable and that has now got me connected via usb. The cable I was using was for charging only.Thank you  CelticWarrior and  linuxbun .